# Is it ok to send gtag('event', 'page_view') on button click

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a website which had 5 screens but now due to customers demand we are converting them to a Single page on which each screen is displayed on scroll-like all 5 screens are showing on one page with scroll, so we had page view for each screen on old version but now because of single page application, how should I send pageview data to google analytics on each section view?[The image shows how before the new work and after the new work screens are displaying.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aovOB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a design question. It's completely up to the person who uses the data. A pageview is not only a metric, it sets the page dimension that is then being used in all events before the next pageview overwrites it. Therefore, when you fire a pageview, you have to make sure the dp/dl dimensions of those pageviews are actually different and indicate what pseudo page users navigate to.

If those pseudo pages have tracked activity on them, then yes, we probably want to set the page for them. But that shouldn't be on button click. Because if the page is scrollable, then now a user can just scroll to our page and get to it efficiently with no button click.

Using pageviews like that is tricky, it entails quite a lot of development. In most cases, simple events suffice, but again, depends on the analyst who consumes the data downstream.